# How to style a html element in typescript / angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to set property to html element but getting an error **Type 'HTMLCollectionOf' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'**

Here is my typescript code---

```js
let elem: HTMLElement= document.getElementsByClassName('notification-top-bar');
      setTimeout(elem.setAttribute("style", "display:none;"), this.duration);
```

Here is my HTML code---

```html
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let n of notifications" class="notification-top-bar" [ngClass]="type" style="display: block;">
    {{message}}  
    <a class="close glyphicon glyphicon-close" (click)="onCloseNotifications($event)"></a>
    <p>{{n}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The method's name is already telling you: "getElementsByClassName". It returns _multiple_ elements and you try to assign it to a single `HTMLElement`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ViewChildren` to get the elements and set their styles. For that you'll have to add a template reference for the elements using which you can get them in your code. Change your template code to add a reference e.g. **`#notification`**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let n of notifications" #notification 
         class="notification-top-bar" [ngClass]="type" 
         style="display: block;">
        {{message}}
        <a class="close glyphicon glyphicon-close" 
           (click)="onCloseNotifications($event)"></a>
        <p>{{n}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can get that in your code like this using **`QueryList`**:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ ... })
export class YourComponent  {

  // Get the template elements
  @ViewChildren('notification') private _notificationsElements:  QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {    

      this._notificationsElements.forEach((element)=>{      
      const htmlElement = element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      // Assigning the property directly
      setTimeout(htmlElement.style.display = 'none',this.duration);
      // OR
      // Using the setAttribute method
      setTimeout(htmlElement.setAttribute("style", "display:none;"),this.duration);
    });

  }
}
```

[**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-stackoverflow-pqyupw?file=app%2Fcomponents%2Fstackoverflow-solution%2Fstackoverflow-solution.component.ts).

Comment: I tried this way but Its throwing an error " Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' ". Is there something which I am missing..?

Comment: You can use `ElementRef` to avoid that error. Check the updated demo and answer.

Answer (score 3):

document.getElementsByClassName returns an array and not single Element.
you can get element by specifying its index like

`document.getElementsByClassName('notification-top-bar')[index]`

also i think you have a typo here , it should be display

`setTimeout(elem.setAttribute("style", "display:none;"), this.duration);`

Comment: I tried giving index but it shows an error "Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement' "   let elem: HTMLElement= document.getElementsByClassName('notification-top-bar')[0];
      setTimeout(elem.setAttribute("style", "display:none;"), this.duration);

Comment: working for me , hiding the html successfully. check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/56rqofkj/27/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you`d better assing and id

```
<div id="notification_id" *ngFor="let n of notifications" class="notification-top-bar"
```

and get it this way:

```
document.getElementById("notification_id")
```

If you do it with classname perhaps you dont know the position of the element.

Comment: I have tried using id, still it shows an error "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null"