# How to use Renderer2's appendChild method with a TemplateRef<any>

Tags: angular

I have a custom directive that I'm trying to use to append an element to:

```html
<ng-template #tooltipContent>
  <span>hello world</span>
</ng-template>

<button 
  tooltipText="tooltip text" 
  [appendedLinkElement]="tooltipContent" 
>
</button>
```

In my `tooltip.directive.ts` custom directive file I can successfully append text like so:

```js
// ...
@Directive({
  selector: '[pslTooltip]',
  // ...
})
export class TooltipDirective ... {
  @Input('tooltipText') tooltipText: string;
  @Input() appendedLinkElement: TemplateRef<any>;
// ...
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  create() {
    this.tooltip = this.renderer.createElement('span');

    this.renderer.appendChild(
      this.tooltip,
      this.renderer.createText(this.tooltipText) // ** this works, but how do I append the TemplateRef? 
    );

    this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
    // ...
  }
}
```

But when I try to replace the appendChild code from above example with the following, I get an error:

```js
// attempt to append the `#tooltipContent` TemplateRef:
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      this.tooltip,
      this.appendedLinkElement,
    );
// I get a console error "TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50737839/11664580
Update the button to replace the two attributes with just one:

```html
<button 
  tooltipContent="tooltip text" 
>
```

(alternatively, the attribute could be `[tooltipContent]="tooltipContent"`, depending on if we want to pass a string or a template)

Update the .ts code as follows:

```js
// ...
@Directive({
    selector: '[pslTooltip]',
    // ...
  })
  export class TooltipDirective ... {
    @Input('tooltipContent') set tooltipContent(value) {
        this._tooltipContent = value
        if (typeof this._tooltipContent !== 'string') {
          this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._tooltipContent)
        }
      }
  // ...
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }
  
    create() {
        this.tooltip = this.renderer.createElement('span');

        if (typeof this._tooltipContent === 'string') {
          this.renderer.appendChild(
            this.tooltip,
            this.renderer.createText(this._tooltipContent) // textNode
          );
        } else {
          // If we are passing an ng-template:
          const embeddedViewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._tooltipContent);
          embeddedViewRef.rootNodes.forEach(n => {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(n, 'style', 'display: block!important;')
            this.renderer.appendChild(this.tooltip, n);
          });
        }
    
        this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
  }
```